# Anet A6: known hotend problems?

Tags: hotend, anet-a6, filament-jam

I've got an Anet A6, modified with bed-leveling sensor etc., which has given me good service for several years. I'm not in a position to spend lots of money on anything fancier, since at present at least it's not immediately contributing to my business.

I almost always have problems extracting the filament after use, and I believe this is getting worse. It's inclined to clump at the bottom, and from the feel I'd say that it's binding at the bottom of the PTFE tube.

I'm not looking forward to stripping things down, since I've got the relative height of the sensor and head calibrated "just right".

Does anybody know of any issues relating to these heads as shipped, e.g. batches going out with liners made of something which isn't quite PTFE?

Alternatively, are there any specific points that I should be looking for? One particular thing that occurs to me as I type is a difference between the diameter of the holes in the nozzle and the PTFE liner resulting in a step at the bottom.